# Increase AVCapturePhotoOutput's maxBracketedCapturePhotoCount value

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapture

I'm trying to take more than 4 images during bracketed capture. Is there a way to edit the [maxBracketedCapturePhotoCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648702-maxbracketedcapturephotocount?language=swift) from the [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From ProCam 5 Tutorial](https://www.procamapp.com/tutorials.html)

"Exposure bracketing is a photography technique where 3  shots or more (4 brackets on iPhone 5 and later, and 3 brackets on older devices)"

So I guess you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a hardware limit. If you want to increase the limit you need to choose a smaller sessionPreset.

Comment: I tried with sessionPresset Preset352x288, but the MaxBracketedCapturePhotoCount is still 4. Any idea?